# C++ overloaded operator with reverse order of associativity

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, associativity

It was very hard to come up with a title... (I'm not a native English speaker.)

```
struct A
{
    int value;
    A operator+(int i) const
    {
        A a;
        a.value=value+i;
        return a;
    };
};
int main(){
    A a;
    a.value=2;
    a=a+2;
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles/works as expected, but when I change a=a+2 to a=2+a, it won't compile anymore.
GCC gives me this error:

```
no match for ”operator+” in ”2 + a”
```

Is there any way to somehow make 2+a work just like a+2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a free function, defined *after* the class

```
struct A
{
   // ...
};

A operator+(int i, const A& a)
{
  return a+i; // assuming commutativity
};
```

also, you might consider defining `A& operator+=(int i);` in `A` an implement both versions of `operator+` as free functions. You might also be interested in Boost.Operators or other helpers to simplify `A`, see my profile for two options.

Comment: Works perfectly! I forgot to make the operator+ in A const, I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, define the inverse operator outside the class:

```
struct A
{
    int value;
    A operator+(int i) const
    {
        A a;
        a.value=value+i;
        return a;
    };
};
//marked inline to prevent a multiple definition
inline A operator+(int i, const A& a)
{
    return a + i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here work fine. However, another option you have is to create a constructor for a single `int` like this:

```
struct A
{
    int value;
    A(int i) {
        value = i;
    }
};
```

This allows integers to get implicitly converted, and allows you to only overload operators for your `struct` instead:

```
A operator+(const A& other) const
{
    // All you need to do is work with an A, and associativity works fine
};
```

Of course, this does allow all integers to get implicitly converted to `A`s, which may or may not be desirable.