# Can you Avoid Multiple Operator Overloads for Mathematical Operators?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, overloading

Say I have a very simple Rational class like the one below:

```
class Rational
{

    int numer;
    int denom;

public:

    Rational(const int& numer, const int& denom) : numer(numer), denom(denom) {}
    void operator*(const Rational& other) { std::cout << "multiply, simple as\n"; }
}
```

All well and good. Then say that I want to be able to multiply my Rational class with an integer, so I add another function to the class:

```
class Rational
{
    
    int numer;
    int denom;
    
public:
    
    Rational(const int& numer, const int& denom) : numer(numer), denom(denom) {}
    void operator*(const Rational& other) { std::cout << "multiply, simple as\n"; }
    void operator*(const int& other) { std::cout << "some math here\n"; }
}
```

Ok no big deal. Except that I can't actually do the following because the order of the parameters would be all wrong:

```
Rational mine(1, 2);
const Rational result = 2 * mine;
```

Ok, one more iteration and I have the following:

```
class Rational
{
    
    int numer;
    int denom;
    
public:
    
    Rational(const int& numer, const int& denom) : numer(numer), denom(denom) {}
    void operator*(const Rational& other) { std::cout << "multiply, simple as\n"; }
    void operator*(const int& other) { std::cout << "some math here\n"; }
    friend void operator*(const int& other, const Rational& mine) { std::cout << "even more math here\n"; }
}
```

What I'm trying to find out is if there's a way that I can avoid having to write the same function twice for every mathematical operation that I'd want my class to support, just so that I can call it with the arguments in whatever order I want. This may well just be how you have to implement this sort of thing within C++'s type system, but it seems a tad annoying to have to add this boilerplate for every mathematical operation that you want your class to support.

Comment: "*Except that I can't actually do the following because the order of the parameters would be all wrong*" - IIRC, C++20 introduces a new feature in overload resolution that actually allows that to work. But I think it only applies to certain operators, and `*` is not one of them.

Comment: Related/dupe: [C++ overloaded operator with reverse order of associativity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118934/)

Comment: Side note: passig primitives like `int` as const references is a pessimization. There is no point to doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue with having a single function is that the type of the left and right operands to `*` would vary (and you would have to use them differently).

This can be solved by fixing both of the argument types to `Rational` and creating an implicit conversion from an `int` `x` to `Rational` `x/1` (which is probably desirable anyways). This way, in `2 * mine`, the `2` will implicitly be converted to `Rational(2, 1) * mine`.

Here's an example:

```cpp
class Rational
{

    int numer;
    int denom;

public:
    // default argument of denom=1 allows implicit conversion from int
    Rational(int numer, int denom = 1) : numer(numer), denom(denom) {}
    friend Rational operator*(const Rational& l, const Rational& r) {
        std::cout << "Rational(" << l.numer << ", " << l.denom
              << ") * Rational(" << r.numer << ", " << r.denom << ")\n";
        // calculate and return result
    }
    friend Rational operator/(const Rational& l, const Rational& r) { /* ... */ }
    friend bool operator==(const Rational& l, const Rational& r) { /* ... */ }
};
```